# How should be paths to p4 sync -L formatted

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to figure out what is correct syntax for `p4 sync -L`. When I try `p4 sync -L //one/of/my/files` it complains that revision is not specified while if I try `p4 sync -L //one/of/my/files@1234` it complains that `@` and `#` are illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the [documentation](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r17.1/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_sync.html) says:

```
a list of valid file arguments in full depot syntax with a valid revision number
```

Revision numbers are `#1`, `#17`, etc. The `@` syntax is used to reference a label name, client name, or changelist number, which are **not** revision numbers.

For more details on this, check `[p4 help revisions][2]`; as it says, you want:

```
`file#n  Revision specifier: The nth revision of file.`
```

So, specify `//one/of/my/files#17`, assuming that revision `17` is the revision of that file that you want to sync.

To see the revisions of your files, use `p4 filelog //one/of/my/files`.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused that `@` is documented under "revision specifiers" [in online documentation](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.1/manuals/cmdref/filespecs.html)

Comment: I agree. This part of Perforce behavior is very confusing. Glad you got it to work!